# How to convert all bype-string variables in a data frame into string variables? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know how to convert byte-string into a string in a data frame. But what I really need to do is convert all variables containing byte-string into variables of strings. Please see the code below to create a data frame df. I need code to first automatically identify which variables containing byte-string and then convert all the variables to strings. In addition, it would be interesting to see how many way to handle this task. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create an example data frame with padas
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'b_char': [b'ABC', b'DEF', b'GHI'],
    'num': [123, 456, 789],
    'char': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
    'c_num': [b'123', b'456', b'789']
    })

# I know how to convert only one variable
df.loc[:,'b_char'] = df['b_char'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Have you already googled your problems or tried some coding on your own?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no luck.